# Kendo Grid and ASP.NET MVC4 wrapper and Conditional .ToClientTemplate()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I would like to put my grids in partials and have a strongly typed model for each grid view that passes the data and specifies if the grid should be rendered to a client template.

For example:

```
--MODEL
    class ProductGridModel
    {
      public List<Products> Products{get;set;}
      public bool LoadAsChildGrid{get;set;}
      public string ParentGrid {get;set;}
    }
--VIEW
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.ProductGridModel>()
    {
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetProducts", "Products", new 
            { orderID=(@Model.LoadAsChildGrid)?"#=OrderID":@Model.OrderID }))
    ...
        .ToClientTemplate(@Model.LoadAsChildGrid)//!!!<-- This can't be done
        .Events(e => e.DataBound((@Model.LoadAsChildGrid)?"BaseGridOnDataBound('grdProducts_#=OrderID#')":""))
    }
--CONTROLLER
    public ActionResult GetProducts(int orderID, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {          
        try
        {
            base.RequireAuthorization(xxxx.StockAdmin, orderID);
            List<Products> products= new ProductManagement().GetProductsByOrderID(orderID);
            return Json(products.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", e.ToString());
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to optionally render ToClientTemplate???. If there is no work around then the only alternative I have is to implement a custom HTmlHelper KendoGridBuilder:

```
public virtual GridBuilder<T> Grid<T>() where T : class;
```

, which I would rather not do at this time. In case I have to extend and implement a grid I have been looking for a step by step guide on how it should be done. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@{
 var grid = (Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.ProductGridModel>()
          ...
       );
}

@if(@Model.LoadAsChildGrid) {
  @grid.ToClientTemplate()
} else {
  @grid
}
```

Comment: Purely maddening. Sometimes the most obvious solutions are the last ones found. Thanks.